# Excel VBA: using the index number in a For loop in a range name

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to use the index number in a For loop in a range name.  Please see below.  I am receiving an "Object required" error.  Thank you for your help.

Sincerely,

Dante

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 2 To 25
    If Not Intersect(range_1, range_ & i) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Error!  range_1 and range_" & i & " overlap!")
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Where is range_1 **Dimmed??**

Comment: what is `range_1` or `range_i`? Named range? You probably know that `range` is an object. so without defining, you are trying to use `intersect`, so error comes.

Comment: Yes, all ranges are properly named elsewhere.

Comment: Now that I understand that these are 25 different variables, I'd suggest re-thinking this. VBA doesn't have a way to check it's own "stuff" like that. Instead, could you use a single variable and set it to the 25 different locations? That would be a lot easier if they are in some kind of pattern, like in A2, A3, A4 ...

Comment: Now I see that you actually create named ranges later in your code. Try giving those names a pattern that you can check for in a `2 to n` type loop or a `For Each nm in ws.Names` type loop. A name like "miscellaneous," as you mentioned will be difficult to check, unless you store them all in your code (not recommended).

Comment: Indeed, I need to re-think this.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I leave the previous answer since, in case of **named** ranges, it's correct and has also been improved by someone else, so users that look for problems with named ranges might find it useful.

On the other hand, what you probably meant is that you **assigned the range to a variable**, such as (of course this is just an example, i cannot know how you made your assignment)

```
Set range_1 = Range("A1")
Set range_2 = Range("A2")
'...
Set range_25 = Range("A25)
```

Unfortunately you cannot loop like that through variable names. But what you can do is creating a collection of ranges, so that you will be able to access them lately by using an index to iterate through them:

```
Dim ranges As Collection: Set ranges = New Collection

ranges.Add range_1
ranges.Add range_2
'...
ranges.Add range_25
```

More in general, add the range to the collection every time you define it. Please note that even if this range will change at a later stage, the range inside your list will change as well because the Add method creates a *shallow copy* of the object (in other words, it is still pointing to the original object).

Now, the collection of ranges is storing your range objects and you will be able to access them by index. For example, in your specific case:

```
For j = 2 To 25
    If Not Intersect(ranges(1), ranges(j)) Is Nothing Then
```

As a good practice, remember that every time you will want to iterate through a "humanly indexable" series of objects/variables as in your case, you will often might want to cast them into a collection because the name of the variables cannot be create/changed from the code itself.

Comment: The Collection idea did it.  Thank you very much for your patience and persistence.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot append numbers to the variable names. The Intersect function takes ranges objects, so you might want to write:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 2 To 25
    If Not Intersect(Range("range_1"), Range("range_" & i)) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Error!  range_1 and range_" & i & " overlap!")
    End If
Next i
```

Of course, I'm assuming that you have properly named your ranges with "range_1", "range_2" etc.

EDIT (by Doug): Here's a version that ensures you are checking in the correct sheet. In this case it's set to ActiveSheet, but you can adjust that. Note that this checks for named ranges actually defined in the worksheet, not ranges set as variables in your code:

```
Sub CheckIntersect()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

Set ws = ActiveSheet 'adjust if necessary
For i = 2 To 25
    If Not Intersect(ws.Range("range_1"), ws.Range("range_" & i)) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Error!  range_1 and range_" & i & " overlap!")
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I often leave off the closing parenthesis on the `Intersect` and so I noticed that  you did too above. It won't compile until it's added.

Comment: Matteo NNZ, Thank you for your help.  Now I receive 'Method' of object '_Global' failed.

Comment: @Dante Picchioni, Do `range_1` and `range_2` exist? Did you name a range in your spreadsheet with this name?

Comment: Yes, all ranges are properly named elsewhere.

Comment: When you execute the macro, the sheet currently activated is the one in which the ranges are named?

Comment: Go into the Formulas tab, Names management and make sure the ranges are really named as you say. The error you get above is normally thrown if the name does not exist.

Comment: Got my vote. For completeness I'd show how to do it with fully-qualified worksheet references, which might solve the problem above, and will certainly solve future ones :).

Comment: @DougGlancy you're right. Im not in front of my laptop now, since from the phone i dont succeed formatting the code (and since this addition makes you deserve some points as well, it's actually an important observation since we talk about references) would you mind suggesting an edit to my answer?

Comment: If I use

If Not Intersect(range_1, range_2) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("Error!  range_1 and range_2 overlap!")
End If

it works fine, so something else must be wrong.

Comment: Aaaah @Dante Picchioni, have you written this somewhere **in your code**? Set range_1 = Range("A1")            (Sorry i cannot format code with the phone)... I mean, when you say "all ranges are properly named elsewhere", you rather mean "all ranges are properly **assigned to the variables** elsewhere"?

Comment: The 25 ranges are formed by adding cells to them when different criteria are met, but if the criteria are never met for a range, yes, I have ensured that at least one cell is added to the range so that it is initialized.

Comment: And I have Dim range_1 As Range for each range.

Comment: I think I found the source of confusion.  These are ranges set as variables in my code.  They are not range names in my worksheet.  I apologize if I created confusion in the title of my question.

Comment: However, I do give each range a name later in my code with range_14.Name = "miscellaneous".  Does doing so affect the variable name?

Comment: @DantePicchioni, I think the second answer that I have added to this post could better help you to keep the current code structure and at the same time loop through the variables as you wanted to do before.